# intranet connection

Tags: networking, intranet

Suppose I am a web services provider, and my consumer A connects to me through A's intranet, the other consumer B also connects me through B's intranet.

Question is, if a hacker controlled A's network, is it possible to the hacker to hack B through me?

What comes to my mind is, since A connected me, and I connected B, the hacker should be able to reach B through me. But other people say it's impossible. Can help to explain?

Comment: Without some details about how the interconnects work (is there a VPN/eVPN, are they on separate machines or VMs, are they on separate broadcast domains, ...) this is impossible to answer to the point.

Comment: Actually I am trying to know if this assumption works, not sure if need to provide details. What if intranet is using VPN? Is it possible to reach B from A through me ?

Comment: *it depends* (on a lot of factors related to your network design, hardware and software), that's my whole point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, hacking or controlling a network means he can control the package's flow, intercept them, modify them, redirect them or something else.

To hack to B through your network, he has to penetrate yours and B's network security. So the answer is depend on yours and B's security.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer has point, not sure why got minus point.